# The loss of semantic segmentation of binary classes with inbalanced data dose not converge

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-segmentation, pytorch, loss-function

I want to segment objects which just occupy a little part of the whole dataset(e.g. the ICDAR 2015 or the person in CamVid). The ratio between positive and negtive sample in pixel-level is about 1:200.

My network, whose backbone is pre-trained VGG16 or ResNet50, could work well in the CamVid dataset with 12 classes. However, when I fine-tuned this network to segment only person in CamVid, the loss will stay around 0.31 and will never decrease even with a truly small learning-rate (like 1e-5). What's more, when training a new model on another dataset (ICDAR 2015) to get the area of text in images, I encountered the same issue.

I built my model with pytorch, and the loss function used by me is Weighted Cross-Entropy Loss.

Could anybody tell me where the problem is? Is that about the loss function? Because I think there is no problem in the model architecture. Really appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: you can find a detailed analysis of this phenomenon in the paper [Focal Loss for Dense Object Detection, (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002).

Comment: @Shai I will have a look on it, Thx~

Answer (score 0):

For the CamVid Dataset, the class of person is too hard to segment with my network. For the ICDAR 2015, I think there is some problems in my processing(like random cropping). In the end, the dataset is really important, and we should put more attention on it.